# Collect all CSS settings that contains a certain color

Tags: javascript, php, css

I want to change color of a Wordpress theme. The problem is that I can not use "search and replace" of the current CSS file. I must override all color settings in a separate file (in a child theme). And there are over 100 different settings with the color.

I need to collect all selectors and the CSS settings that contains this color and overide it by a new CSS file.

**I would like this:**

```
#some_id{width:100px;background:#ff0000;}
.some_class{height:100px;background:#ff0000;color:#ff0000;}
a:hover{color:#ff0000;font:12px/arial}
```

**To become this:**

```
#some_id,.some_class{background:#ff0000;}
.some_class,a:hover{color:#ff0000;}
```

Any one know a tool or script for that?

I know some basic PHP and Javascript.

Comment: Maybe you can use javascript for this task, but its a pain for perfomance check every elemnet on the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Does your wordpress theme have different "skins" for different colors? Like is there a setting where you can pick from a few limited pre-set colors that will turn all these 100+ elements that color? If so there is probably a CSS file somewhere for each color option they provided (for example green.css, blue.css). you can copy/paste the code from there to find all the selectors